# Is It Possible To Launch A Lync Session And Invite Tech And External User From A C# Web App?

Tags: c#, asp.net, lync, lync-2010, ucma

I'm tasked with writing a web app that will connect an internal employee and an external client while logging Case details. Our company recently switched over to Lync, so I'm a bit lost on the API for doing this.

Ideally, this would be a web app (C# & ASP.NET) so that the customer support department doesn't have to install something to every workstation. It would also mimic the behavior found in [this article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/communicator-help/create-a-meeting-request-for-an-online-meeting-or-conference-call-HA101990914.aspx) for sending an email to allow external users to connect.

Is UCMA required for this? We have a generic Lync account that could be used by a service to facilitate these requests if that would be more appropriate. I can also force the issue for using a desktop app if need be.

I'm just having a hell of a time finding the right API calls to make this happen on MSDN so any links to docs or tutorials would be a huge help.

Some research that doesn't *quite* point out what needs to be done:
[UCMA: Chat with users not in AD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909410/ucma-chat-with-users-not-in-ad)
[How do I Invite a user by email to a Lync 2010 chat session using the API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382160/how-do-i-invite-a-user-by-email-to-a-lync-2010-chat-session-using-the-api)

Comment: So your internal users are using lync, but your external users aren't, hence the need for the web app? Have you looked at the lync web client? If so, where does this come up short for you? Just trying to understand the scenario a bit more...

Comment: The need for the web app is because we need to log some things to a CRM system while sending the invitation. For audit purposes, they don't want our tech support team sending invitations directly from Lync.

I fully expect that the external clients will use the Lync web client more often than not.

Answer (score 0):

you should take a look at this sample located at :%Program Files%Microsoft UCMA 3.0\SDK\Core\Sample Applications\Reference\ContactCenter

You'll find more details here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285604.aspx

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

You should also take a look at UCWA - Microsoft's Unified Communications Web API.

[Unified Communications Web API](https://ucwa.lync.com/about/about-ucwa)

It's a great platform for adding Lync functionality into your Web application, has an [Online Demo](https://ucwa.lync.com/explore) with full source code as well.